# Проблема с установкой библиотеки OpenAi

Tags: python, установка, python-openai

Несколько раз пытался установить библиотеку, но при написания кода при команде

> from openai import OpenAI

Пишет библиотека не найдена

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробывал команды

> pip install openai

> pip install --upgrade openai

Вводил как в терминал Вилжа так и в CMD

Просьба помочь
p.s возможно я не правильно как-то устанавливаю. Прошу объяснить, в инете ничего подобного не нашёл

Comment: Код запускается?

Comment: В какое окружение питона ставили, такое и выбирайте в `IDE`. Где-то там справа внизу, например, возможно, этот выбор на рамке `IDE`. Там написано `python` и версия, скорее всего. И там можно выбрать окружение из списка доступных. Покажите полный скриншот использованной вами среды разработки.

Answer (score 0):

1 создай окружение - python3 -m venv **customName_env**
2 зайди в создание окружение source customName_env/bin/activate
3 установи PIP: python3 -m pip install
теперь вводи